# How can I create a view by passing the name from a parameter? (like: CREATE VIEW @ViewName )

Tags: sql, view, parameters

How can I use a parameter that stands for a view name which I can pass into CREATE VIEW statement in SQL?

```
DECLARE @ViewName VARCHAR(40) = 'V_fooo'
CREATE VIEW @ViewName 
AS
SELECT  * from foods
```

Does not work due to a syntax error. How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the purpose of this query ?? inline-table valued function will they be any good for your requirement ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do this using DYNAMIC SQL.

```
DECLARE @ViewName VARCHAR(40) = 'V_fooo'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'CREATE VIEW ' + @ViewName +'
AS
SELECT  * from foods'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

### [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5184e6/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @View_Name NVARCHAR(128);

SET @View_Name = 'V_fooo'

SET @Sql = N'CREATE VIEW  ' + QUOTENAME(@View_Name) +
           N' AS SELECT * FROM dbo.foo_table'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```